# Detect how long a push button is being pressed?

Tags: programming, button

I would like to detect how long the state on/off is going on for. Is there a way to do that? I would like to do that for two reasons:

1. I would be able to make a very simple toggle button. (I know about the other way with the old value and new value).
2. I can make the button being pressed for a long time be like a return button.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: You would need to use [`millis()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Millis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs a combination of patterns.

First, the button pin needs to be debounced. This can be done with the "blink-without-delay"-pattern where the button pin is sampled with a low period (40 ms in the example code below).

Second, a simple state-machine is needed to keep track of the button state but also if the return button action function, doReturnButton(), has already been called.

The button is assumed to be connected from GND to pin4. The button action function, doButton(), is called when the button is pushed (goes LOW).

```
const int buttonPin = 4;
const unsigned long debounceInterval = 40;
const unsigned long returnInverval = 400;
bool buttonState = true;
bool returnButtonState = false;
unsigned long buttonDownMillis = 0L;

void doButton()
{
  Serial.print(buttonDownMillis);
  Serial.println(F(":doButton"));
}

void doReturnButton()
{
  Serial.print(buttonDownMillis);
  Serial.println(F(":doReturnButton"));
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(57600);
  while (!Serial);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop()
{
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  static unsigned long previousMillis = 0L;

  // Check if it is time to sample the button pin
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= debounceInterval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    // Did the button change
    if (digitalRead(buttonPin) != buttonState) {
      buttonState = !buttonState;

      // Was the button released
      if (buttonState) {
        returnButtonState = false;
      }

      // Was the button pushed
      else {
        buttonDownMillis = currentMillis;
        returnButtonState = true;
        doButton();
      }
    }

    // Check if button was pushed and time for return action
    else if (returnButtonState) {
      if (currentMillis - buttonDownMillis >= returnInverval) {
        returnButtonState = false;
        doReturnButton();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What does the code do?

1. It samples the button pin with a debounce interval.
2. If the button state changes: 
   a. High to Low it calls the doButton() function and captures a timestamp. It also allows detect of return time interval. 
   b. Low to High. Return time interval is not allowed any more.
3. It checks if the return time interval has elapsed and if so calls the doReturnButton() function. The detect is then not allowed any more.

The doButton() function is called when the button is pushed (transition high to low), only once. The doReturnButton() function is called if the return time limit exceeds and the button is still low. Both are only called once per push (transition high to low).

To avoid the multiple transitions that occur when a button is pushed a debounce time period is used. The can also be done in hardware with a RC-circuit.

With some abstraction it could be rewritten as:

```
#include <Timemark.h>

Timemark debounce(40);
Timemark buttonHold(400);

const int buttonPin = 4;
bool buttonState;

void doButton()
{
  Serial.println(F("doButton"));
}

void doReturnButton()
{
  Serial.println(F("doReturnButton"));
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println(F("started"));
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  debounce.start();
}

void loop()
{
  if (debounce.expired()) {
    bool currentState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
    if (currentState != buttonState) {
      buttonState = currentState;
      if (buttonState) {
        if (buttonHold.expired())
          doReturnButton();
        else
          doButton();
        buttonHold.stop();
      }
      else {
        buttonHold.start();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This also demonstrates the callback on the release of the button. The [Timemark](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Arduino-Timemark) class hides all the time intervals, expire calculations, etc.

Cheers!

Comment: Isn't this just making a toggle button?

Comment: It calls doButton when the button is pushed and doReturnButton if the button is still pressed after a time limit.

Comment: Ah sorry I just got to understand the code better hang on.

Comment: I am genuinely sorry but can you please explain each part of the code? it would really help me understand it as well as broaden my knowledge of arduino.

Comment: On a long press, you will `doButton()` **and** `doReturnButton()`. I do not thing this is what the OP wants, although the question is not clear on this regard.

Comment: I avoided that as it actually adds some complexity to the "state machine". The "callback" has to be delayed for the return button interval. From an UI point of view the button feedback becomes "sluggish". It is a bit like mouse click and double click. You get both events and the application has to add logic on top of that. But it is a good point!

Comment: You could get a slightly more responsive UI – and not really more complicated – by calling the “short press” callback on the button release event: that's when you know it was actually a short press.

Comment: I am so sorry. For some reason, I did not get the notification of the comments and that the answer changed. I believe this is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I've just seen your updated answer with a Timer class. This would certainly provide a terrible user experience. If you tell the user that, for performing some action, a long press is needed, he will typically press the button and hold it down until he sees the action is taken. But your code waits for the user to release the button... which leads to a dead lock. I've previously commented that the release event is the best time to fire the “short press” callback, but that does not apply to the “long press”.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Please feel free to edit the code. The idea was to illustrate different approaches not the ultimate correct version. The last approach was callback on release which what typical GUI events click/doubleClick do. Other GUI events are mouseDown and mouseUp. But again I can only agree that this is not the perfect user experience for push buttons.

Answer (score 1):

1. Note the time the switch is pressed (with `millis()`)
2. Note the time the switch was released.
3. When the switch is released calculate the difference. If it is a "long" time do one thing, otherwise do something else.

Comment: But won't millis() just detect how long the program was running?

Comment: @Jack Think about it. You're not looking at millis() directly, but at the difference between two consecutive calls.